# import a web service in an android project

Tags: android, web-services

I am a beginner in android development and i would like to know if i can import a web service in an android project. To explain more, i have a web service and i want to add it in my android project so i can have access to the parameters of it's methodes cause the wsdl file doesn't show the names of the parameters but only the word "parameters" as a parameter in every methode.

I "google it" a lot and i find this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.ui.doc.user/tasks/tcrtwsdl.html) but i didn't find anything else.

Please help me out.

Comment: Change your profile picture.

Comment: Yes its Not suitable here in stackoverflow.

Comment: ok then...picture changed.Now please vote for my question so i take an answer :D

Comment: Yes Please edit your answer a little. its giving me error "
You last voted on this question
23 mins ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this question is edited"

Comment: Upvaoted and sorry for inconvenience. I have worked in web services using made in php and asp.net. if you need help in this regard. im here for you :)